# Why use constructor function?

Tags: solidity, constructor

What is the big difference between:

```
contract Crowdsale {
    MintableToken public token;
    uint256 public someInt;
    [...]

    function Crowdsale (uint256 _constructorArgument){
      someInt = _constructorArgument;
      token   = createTokenContract();
    }

    function createTokenContract() internal returns (MintableToken) 
    {
      return new MintableToken();
    }
```

and

```
contract Crowdsale {
    MintableToken public token = new MintableToken();
    uint256 public someInt     = theValueIWouldPassAsConstrArgument;
    [...]

    function Crowdsale (){

    }
```

The second version is much cleaner imho. I have less code. No need for constructor Arguments...

What is the difference? I would prefer the second version. But maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second version will only work with hardcoded values.

How would you instantiate a new object with different paramters, dynamically?

You can't do this:

```
Crowdsale c = new Crowdsale(10);
```

Comment: Ok, makes sense. But there is no difference? Actually most examples do not need dynamic values. If this is the only reason I would stick to my version as long as I do not need dynamic creation...